# Availability of library for solving generalized network flow problems

Tags: solver, or-tools, network-flow, software

I need to solve a large-scale **generalized** network flow problem.

For reference, it is a pure network-flow model with the exception that arcs have a positive coefficient applied to flow on them. In my case I have supply nodes from which I send flow to sink nodes that absorb them. The flow, however, incurs a loss depending on the distance between the two nodes.

[Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow) has an excellent network-flow solver, but only for pure flow models. Is there a publicly available and reasonably mature solver for generalized network models? If not, could anyone recommend an easy-to-implement solution algorithm that I can implement myself quickly?

Comment: Have you tried solving it as an LP?

Comment: I did not yet, but it is the first thing I will try next week. I prefer originating flows to be integer, but probably can live with fractional values.

I am kind of spoiled with the speed of Google's network flow solver, so hoping to find something like that for the generalized version. Also, I may have to solve this problem many times so computational requirement may be an issue.

Comment: Unlike pure network flow, generalized network flow will not typically yield integer optimal solutions.

Comment: Good point, did not think of that. Given that commercial LP solvers are very fast these days, it should do it for me. 

Still I am curious about the availability of generalized network flow solvers. For very large problems it could make a significant difference compared to an LP solver.

Comment: What is the theoretical or computational evidence that there is a specialized algorithm for generalized network flows that will beat a general LP optimizer? Is there any collection of benchmark instances of generalized network problems?

Comment: My internet search found several papers developing specialized algos for GNF. One was how to extend the network simplex for GNF. I mean, if a separate model category for GNF is accepted, then I imagine it is because it has an important structure that can be exploited in a solution method.